# How to apply switch case in python to return some value based on variable's value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I use switch case alternative for below scenario?

If `x` is any one of `5, 6, 7, 8`, I want to return `0`,
if `x` is any one of `9, 10, 11, 12`, I want to return `1`,
if `x` is any one of `13, 14, 15, 16`, I want to return `2`,
if `x` is any one of `17, 18, 19, 20`, I want to return `3`.

I came across something like this for single value, but not sure how I can use similar syntax for above scenario.

```
def group(x):
 return {
  [5, 6, 7, 8]: 0,
  [9, 10, 11, 12]: 1,
  [13, 14, 15, 16]: 2,
  [17, 18, 19, 20]: 3,
  }.get(x, "Invalid")
```

Can someone please help me to conclude if I can use above way or only if else is the option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tuples as keys for the dictionary and then use a generator to get the value or return `'Invalid'` if the number isn't in any of the keys, for example:

```
def group(x):
    d = {(5, 6, 7, 8): 0, (9, 10, 11, 12): 1, (13, 14, 15, 16): 2, (17, 18, 19, 20): 3}
    return next((d[i] for i in d if x in i), 'Invalid')

print group(11)
print group(17)
```

`next()` will find the next key that has `x` in it and return the value

output:

```
1
3
```

Comment: Not that it will matter a whole lot in most cases, but you should use sets instead of tuples for the the keys: `d = {{5, 6, 7, 8}: 0, {9, 10, 11, 12}: 1, ...`. This will give you O(1) lookups vs. O(n). See here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: but how can sets be dictionary keys, aren't `sets` unhashable type.

Comment: @Bijoy One can use `frozenset`s: `d = {frozenset({5, 6, 7, 8}): 0...}`

Comment: @Bijoy Yes, normal sets are unhashable and therefore can't be used as dictionary keys

Comment: Yea, my bad. I was thinking of `frozenset`s but said the other. Time for bed I guess. :)

Comment: or `return next((v for g, v in d.items() if x in g))`. Also you can use an optional second argument to `next` for a default value (in case of StopIteration). `next(..., "Invalid")`

Comment: @AdamSmith `next(..., 'Invalid')` looks better, ill update the answer thanks!

Comment: Sure this works, but it severely defeats the purpose of a dict. The moment you have to involve iteration with a dict for lookup, you know you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Lists cannot serve as dictionary keys. Create a separate dictionary item for each key:

```
return {5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1, ..., 12: 1, ...}.get(x, "Invalid")
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, so that if there is any alternative to do it which I haven't thought of...

Comment: @DYZ if you ignore the arithmetic solution, yes ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith The arithmetic solution is very specific to these particular numbers.

Comment: This is the best solution in terms of the fact that it respects the use of a dict, and works because the ranges (appear to be) mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Sweety You should seriously consider this as the best possible solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic for this

```
def group(x):
    """5-8   -> 0
       9-12  -> 1
       13-16 -> 2
       17-20 -> 3
    """
    # scale down our starting values, so 5-8 -> 0-3
    return (x-5) // 4
```

If you want a generalized solution to this for any arbitrary grouping -> return value pairings, you'll need to write a function factory.

```
def selector(groups, return_values, fallback=None):
    if len(groups) != len(return_values):
        raise ValueError("groups and return_values must have equal length")
    def wrapped(needle):
        nonlocal groups, return_values, fallback
        for grp, retval in zip(groups, return_values):
            if needle in grp:
                return retval
        # if no matches
        return fallback
    return wrapped
```

Then you can do:

```
group = selector([(5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12),
                  (13, 14, 15, 16), (17, 18, 19, 20)],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 fallback="Invalid")
group(3)
```